# ASP Core. "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0" Does not have decimal.Round()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert ASP.Net MVC 5 project to ASP Core. and in my code i have this

```
var answer1present = decimal.Round(answer1present, 2);
var answer2present = decimal.Round(answer2present, 2);
```

In asp core i am getting error "Round is not defined" so i check decimal struct and i can not see a method defined Round(). but in previous version of asp MVC i had this method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this package to your dependencies section of `project.json` file.

```
"System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.3.0"
```

Then you can use

```
Math.Round(26.546, 2)
```

Comment: Why don't use Math.Round(26.546, 2) ?